# p:commandLink inside p:accordionPanel works in IE, but not in FF/Chrome

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, commandlink

I have the following view:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/cmsLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="rightPane">
        <div class="rightPane_header">
            <p:tabMenu activeIndex="0">
                <p:menuitem value="Home" url="/userHome.faces" />
                ...
            </p:tabMenu>
        </div >
        <div class="rightPaneData"> 
            <h:form>
                <p:growl id="growl"/>

                <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="0" dynamic="false" cache="false">
                    <p:tab title="My Document">
                        <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{documentController.getMyDocumentsForHome()}" />
                        <p:dataTable id="homeMyDocTable" var="myDocument" value="#{documentController.myDocuments}" rowKey="#{myDocument.docId}"
                            selection="#{documentController.selectedDocument}" selectionMode="single">
                            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{documentController.viewDocumentDetailPage}" />
                            <p:column headerText="Document Number" id="homeMyDocNumber" styleClass="FixedcolumnWidth">
                                <h:outputText value="#{myDocument.docId}" />
                            </p:column>
                            ...
                        </p:dataTable>
                        <p:commandLink value="More.." rendered="#{documentController.myDocMoreStatus}" action="#{documentController.viewMyDocumentPage}" />
                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The `<p:commandLink>` with value of "More.." works fine in IE, but not in FF/Chrome. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please exclude all possible causes listed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183 My guess is that it's just #2. Further it would also be helpful if you elaborate "doesn't work" in developer's terms instead of in enduser's terms. What exactly happens (not)? Track the HTTP traffic, debug the JSF code, etc.

Comment: thanks @BalusC ,this link is mean to open a new page but somehow that doesn't work, I am still debugging it will post the details, meanwhile I found it shows different behavior on IE and Mozilla Firefox. Will update you. Thx